# Implementing special linked-list method in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Is it possible to create a linked list in Java, with the ability to add new links anywhere in the middle (not just at the beginning or end) of the list -- if possible, without copy-pasting in memory large parts of the list to accommodate for entry of a new link?

If so, please post your example!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You should post the important parts of your code (what have you tried?) in order for people to understand it better and show that you have put some effort into solving this problem by yourself. I suggest that you read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The answer is yes.  Do your own homework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LinkedList to do this.

```
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    ints.add(i / 2, i);
System.out.println(ints);
```

prints

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

As you can see it has been adding entries in the middle of the list.

Comment: and in constant/linear time as well :)

Comment: Good to hear its in constant time. Do you know how to find the implementation? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Its in the `src.zip` of your JDK. If you use an IDE you can `<ctrl>+<click>` a class to see its source.

Answer (score 2):

The [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class in Java already does this, by means of its [`add(index, element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo code something link this is a good place to start:

```
public LinkedList<E> implements List<E>{
    ...

    public void add(int index, E element){
        Node<E> current=findNodeAt(index);
        //add in your logic to insert this node at this location
        //probably something like (depending on your linking)
        element.setNext({current nodes next value})
        current.setnext(element);      
    }

    private Node<E> findNodeAt(index){
        //iterate through list until you reach the index or end of the list
        //then return that node
    }

    ...
}





public Node<E>{
    private Node<E> next;
    ... 

    Node<E> setNext(Node<E> next){
        Node<E> previousNext=next;
        this.next=next;
        return previousNext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` Implements 'List' Interface, and it has the add method you need : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Comment: I was actually looking in the setter methods to find this, but you're absolutely right! Thank you. Is there any way to see the implementation of this method? I've tried CTRL clicking the method in Netbeans, but it isn't very informative.